# for the comparison - basic or comparative adjective?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-construction

Suppose, If I am comparing two segments and then I want to compare their areas and need to find smaller one.

> The segment having a ***smaller*** area can then be chosen as a vehicle.

> The segment having a ***small*** area can then be chosen as a vehicle.

What would be correct? I know I should use a comparative adjective, but in this case I am confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *The segment having a **smaller** area can then be chosen as a vehicle.*

This choice is closer to correct. I perceive your problem *not* as coming from the selection of an appropriate adjective (“smaller” is correct), but from matching the articles in the sentence.

> ***The** segment having **a** smaller area can then be chosen as **a** vehicle.*

becomes:

> **The** segment having **the** smaller area can then be chosen as **the** vehicle.

The reasoning here is that you are referring to a *specific* thing in each case.

- “**The** segment...” *(we're going to pick a specific one out of a pair)*
- “...**the** smaller area...” *(out of the two areas, this one meets the specific criterion)*
- “...as **the** vehicle.” *(now, with this one, you actually have a choice to make. I don't have all the context, but basically it depends on whether or not this is the only vehicle being produced by whatever's taking place or one of multiple vehicles. I also don't know what you mean by “vehicle” in this case.)*

---

The other minor issue is that “having” is awkward. In this case (an object with a static trait), it would be better to phrase it as “the [object] **with** the [trait]” so that the whole thing becomes:

> The segment **with** the smaller area can then be chosen as the vehicle.

Comment: thanks for the analysis and very clear explanation. its great.

Answer (score 2):

*Smaller* is the comparative form of *small*, so you want to go with your first sentence.

Imagine that you would consider anything under, say, 1 unit as "small", and you have a segment that is 0.5 units and another that is 0.48 units.  If you said "choose the segment having a small area", I could say "but they're both small!  I need to pick just one of them!"

Conversely, if the segments are 10 units and 11 units, I could say "but neither of them is small!  Now I can't choose a vehicle!".

By using *smaller*, you establish that I am only comparing the segments to each other, instead of comparing both of them to some outside standard.